# unable to find downloaded file after archive file is successfully downloaded from AWS glacier?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-glacier

Recently, I have been trying to use glacier for archiving. I am using [glacier-cmd package](https://github.com/uskudnik/amazon-glacier-cmd-interface)

I have managed to upload the archive to the glacier vaults.
but now when I tried downloading the archive, I cannot locate the downloaded archive in my local machine. Does anybody have got any idea regarding this? It would be very much helpful.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

number of request means number of objects on that archive.